# Add username or any user authentication related field like first name, last name etc in model forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I am creating a project in django in which I have two diff users i.e. Customers and restaurants.
I am creating a model for Menu in which I want add to add restaurant name in models directly(user name in this case) instead of taking input thorough forms every time.Also if possible if can take name from another field like this which is part of login system?

Models.py

```
class menu_details(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    dish_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    dish_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=food_type, default='veg')
    price = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=5000)
    image = models.ImageField0(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "menu_details"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, I think you need a Foreign Key Field pointing to the User infromation.

```
field_name= models.ForeignKey(User, help_text="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can access all the data from a user instance in views, for example:

```
this_menu = menu_details.objects.get(pk=1)

restaurant_name = this_menu.field_name.first_name
restaurant_email = this_menu.field_name.email
```

Or in templates:

```
{{ this_menu.field_name.first_name }}
{{ this_menu.field_name.email}}
```

Comment: Sort of but i need particular value from there, like username or first name.

Comment: @MayankTola I updated the answer explaining how can you access the info later.

Comment: ok so it will store all the data related to user in 'field name' and I can get access to which ever I want right?

Comment: @MayankTola That's right. I recommend the following tutorial for Django: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website

Comment: Not really "storing" all the data in "Field name", just relating both models.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the answer as correct if it worked for you so other users find the solution to the same problem in the future. Best!